# React Native JS debugger DevTools preview not readable

Tags: react-native

js debugger output:

[image]

When making network request via Axios and opening js debugger network tab preview shows only jibberish.

How can I see response in json and if that's not possible what other tools are available to debug network requests (like I used to in Angular, .... applications)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.